# Audio file not Supported

Tags: music, music-player

So I just went from the LG ThinQ to the LG Velvet and transferred some of my music over. However, when I try to play certain songs, they come up as "file not supported". They will play on my ThinQ but NOT my Velvet. Is there some sort of software issue?

Comment: What types of audio files are you talking about? MP3, M4A, FLAC or a file created with a special codec?

Comment: They are merely Mp3 and WMA files.

Comment: Hello. Which app are you using to play those files? Have you tried using a different app, such as VLC app or PowerAmp?

Comment: Hello, in both cases, I have been using just the standard music app that comes with the phones. It is just strange to hear it works for one but not the other.